# Linux - looking for a way to produce analog effects for video

Tags: video, linux, analog

I am looking for a way to make analog video effects like those:

*You may want to turn the volume down a bit*:

If there's no convinient way to do it i can head to electronics stackexchange for instructions on how to make some effect adding PCB's

Comment: Can you be more specific about which effects? I can explain most of them, but it's not clear which ones you're talking about. I see the analog equivalent of FCP's BadTV, Kaleidoscope, Insect Eye, as well as some that look like simple programs running on a C64 or TRS-80 era computer.

Comment: @user1118321 i mean 0:00 to 0:03, 0:14, 0:26, whirl at 2:49, and etc. i'm just looking for a software/or even algorithm to make them. I'm a programmer so i can write some stuff. My favourite would be 2:50 to 3:00, that blackness at 0:59. Of course they dont have to be exactly the same. just looking for a way to make some similiar effects.

Comment: I can't watch the video: "The uploader has not made this video available in your country"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried compositing it with Blender? I think you can achieve pretty much what you want with it.

Look for tutorials but [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1C92wiIkNI) is an example. [This](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/354-tutorial-a-2d-hologram-in-blender-part-1.html) is a tutorial for creating a hologram, but you can take the part on how to create the horizontal lines from the cathodic ray TVs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew blender could edit videos but i didn't know it had so much power! It's much better than the stuff i used before.

Comment: It really is!, I am amazed how open source free software can be much better than comercial counterparts.